# Catching error from the left operand of the pipe

Tags: bash

I have this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

ERROR=0

while ((ERROR == 0)); do
  /home/super/bin/vmpull 2>&1 | tee /home/super/logs/vmpull.log
  ERROR=$?
  /home/super/bin/vmsync 2>&1 | tee /home/super/logs/vmsync.log
  ERROR=$?
  sleep 1d

done
```

I need to run the two internal commands in sequence till any of those return an error.
But here I am catching the exit status of `tee` and not the `vmpull` or `vmsync`
Thats why the loop never breaks even if the internal scripts error out.

How can I catch the errors of `vmpull` or `vmsync` and still do the piping?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the array PIPESTATUS

Comment: Thank you. Why didn't you put it as an answer?

Comment: Answering common questions like this feels  too much like cherry-picking for rep. The first assignment of ERROR is pointless, and the loop will not terminate if vmpull fails; you'll need a break to make that happen.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ERROR seems like a common enough name, why can't it be a user-set environment variable?

Comment: @William Pursell No, I don't need a break there. This is exactly the logic I want. I want the `vmsync` to carry on even if `vmpull` fails. But I don't want to start a new loop if any of the commands failed.

Comment: @r.sendecky Your logic is flawed. It's okay that you want `vmsync`to be attempted even if `vmpull` fails, but your logic will not exit the loop if *either* fails but only if `vmsync` fails since you overwrite `ERROR` with `vmsync`'s exit status. You need separate variables for each and you need to check both in your `while` condition: `while [ $ERR1 -a $ERR2 ]`.

Comment: @ooga True. Thanks. I updated it with an if statement `if [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} != 0 ]]; then ERROR=1; fi` That should do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729099/catching-error-from-the-left-operand-of-the-pipe#comment38359734_24729099) suggested, you can use `PIPESTATUS`.

```
  /home/super/bin/vmpull 2>&1 | tee /home/super/logs/vmpull.log
  ERROR=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Optionally you can just do `ERROR=$PIPESTATUS` since you're accessing the first element.

And another way in your case is to hide your `tee` command with process substition:

```
  /home/super/bin/vmpull > >(exec tee /home/super/logs/vmpull.log) 2>&1
  ERROR=$?
```

`exec` is optional to prevent unnecessary fork and you may remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and other tips. I did not know about the `PIPESTATUS` You learn something new every day.

Comment: @r.sendecky Another options is `set -o pipefail` which causes the exit status to be that of the first command to fail, or that of the final command if the previous commands succeed. Then `$?` will work as the OP originally used it.

Comment: Yes granting `tee` would not fail in any way. It's probably unlikely so it's one thing to consider as well.